# Don't load JS scripts for bots (Google and other) for better performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, facebook-social-plugins

Just curious, if somebody did this already. How about to skip the load of social js like Facebook like box, Google+, Twitter, etc. in order to improve performance and loading time for bots?

Would this be considered as kind of hack and would affect ranking?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. Googlebot (and no doubt others) will download JS and use this for indexing. If the bot doesn't want to download scripts, then it doesn't have to - but you should give it the choice.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually, I mean to not even put the JS on the page. My point is to skip all the JS I see as "high priority recommendation" in Google Page Speed to be deferred loaded or removed.